# Path.scale gets ignored if new points are added in onFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

When drawing a path, if I add points the previously set scale gets overwritten/ignored.

I cannot call scale after drawing is complete as it is being drawn while the user is watching over a long period of time. I cannot call scale within my loop where I add new points because then it gets bigger and bigger and flies off the screen.

**This will work**

```
  var line = new Path();

  line.strokeColor = 'orange';

  line.add(50,50);
  line.add(100,50);

  line.scale(10);

  function onFrame() {
    line.rotate(1);
  }
```

**This will not**

```
  var line = new Path();

  line.strokeColor = 'orange';

  line.scale(10);

  function onFrame() {
    line.add(50,50);
    line.add(100,50);
    line.rotate(1);
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YwCj9AdcLK8kDbJaTwz9?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

By default, matrices including scale are applied immediately to the path's children rather than being a property of the path. To change this behaviour you can use `item.applyMatrix` to prevent the scale transform being immediately applied.

```
  var line = new Path();
  line.applyMatrix = false;

  line.strokeColor = 'orange';

  line.scale(10);

  function onFrame() {
    line.add(50,50);
    line.add(100,50);
    line.rotate(1);
  }
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/paperjs/applymatrix/paperjs/4EIRSGzcaUI/seKoNT-PSpwJ